# Child Healthcare costs - Statistics by age

Tags: united-states, healthcare, children

Are there statistics, both current and projected, on healthcare costs (absolute dollar amounts) in the USA for children at various ages?

I googled this and found this study: http://www.healthcostinstitute.org/files/Age-Curve-Study_0.pdf but it does not have "absolute" dollar amounts. Only relative indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [2012 article from the american academy of pediatrics](https://www.aap.org/en-us/professional-resources/practice-support/pediatric-cost-model/pages/Pediatric-Cost-Model.aspx) has some numbers on the costs paid by insurers for pediatric healthcare.

This [2012 paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23184117) looks at the patterns and costs of health care use in children with medical complexity.

This [CDC paper](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/series/sr_10/sr10_196.pdf) doesnt talk directly about the costs of pediatric healthcare, but they do reference several sources on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, Pabtorre but it looks like this paper is behind a paywall. I am specifically looking for *out-of-pocket* health cost statistics by age-group (children, toddler, pre-teen etc)

Comment: hmm... 
Try the health expenditure datasets in Quandl... maybe you can get the numbers you need from there? 
https://www.quandl.com/collections/usa/usa-health-data

Comment: Alright. After some research, I found this link: http://www.healthcostinstitute.org/childrens-health-spending-2009-2012

Comment: nice find. Best of luck with your project.